# Hide Authorization Token from Request Headers in browser for headless magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, nginx, react

We are using reactJS as frontend for magento 2 website using magento 2 rest APIs. But the authorization token is visible in the browser dev tools posing security risk.

[image]

Kindly suggest a way to hide authorization token from browser.

Also we want to block API hits from any other tool (e.g. postman,arc etc.) and allow API hits only through reactJS end.

Comment: Did you get any solution for hiding token?